# Como obter uma determinada tag html de um site externo?

Tags: php

##### Fiz o seguinte código abaixo

```php
<?php

    $url = "https://pt.clubcooee.com/settings/changename?token=24075208-1660433091-a355f7ce9bc39f2e8a2a09f30107ca3d&ms=1";

    $dados = file_get_contents($url);

    $var = explode('<h3 class="font-m">', $dados);
    $var2 = explode('</div>', $var[1]);

    print '<h3 class="font-m">'.$var2[1];
```

<sup>**Obs**.: As vezes é necessário mudar o final da url "ms=1" pra "ms=2", para assim conseguir logar na página!</sup>

[image]

A parte que está selecionada na imagem acima é o que desejo capturar! Porém, sempre me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\Programas\xamp\htdocs\trade\index.php on line 8
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\Programas\xamp\htdocs\trade\index.php on line 10

Comment: Use um analisador de HTML. Veja [DOMDocument::loadHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Comment: Isso não funcionaria, eu preciso fazer um request no login do site.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

#### Não é recomendado! porém utilizei a função [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all)

Para isso criei uma simples *pattern*, para obter os respectivos valores. No entanto, com apenas a função [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents) não foi possível localizar esses dados, pois o site redireciona para área de login, por não conter as **sessões** e/ou **cookies** na requisição. Por isso criei uma chamada [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-init.php) para a determinada url. De fato funciona! mesmo sem efetuar o login na página, da seguinte maneira:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://pt.clubcooee.com/settings/changename?token=24075208-1660433091-a355f7ce9bc39f2e8a2a09f30107ca3d&ms=1",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
        "Host: pt.clubcooee.com",
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.67"
    ),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookie.log",
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookie.log",
    CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4
));
```

Após o código acima, criei uma variável chamada `$dados` para executar os parâmetros do curl.

```
$dados = curl_exec($ch);
```

Em seguida vem a função preg_match_all

```php
preg_match_all('/<h3 class="font-m">([^<]*)<\/h3>([^.\r\n]*)<\/div>/', $dados, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Utilizei a flag [`PREG_SET_ORDER`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pcre.constants.php) para que os dados da matriz sejam retornados de forma ordenada!

Contudo, basta imprimir o resultado na página!

```php
echo trim(strip_tags($matches[0][0]));
```

<sup>a função `strip_tags()` serve para remover as tags de html presentes entre os textos, como `<br>` e etc..</sup>

> "Suas mudanças de nome até agora 06/08/21 21:25 testbug01425451 -> testbug00071"

Comment: Bom, eu fiz todo o código e ainda assim apresenta o erro: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in index.php on line 28

Comment: @LODSX me informe a linha 28

Comment: Fiz uns ajustes aqui e consegui, muito obrigado amigo! xD